# Regex lazy matching does not match string matched by greedy expression

Tags: regex, grep

Suppose I have the following text file (called `test.txt`):

```
\centerline{\includegraphics[width=0.50 \columnwidth]{example_graph.pdf}}
\centerline{\includegraphics[width=0.5 \columnwidth]{coarse_grain_illustration.png}}
\centerline{\includegraphics[width= 0.8 \columnwidth]{1y26_energy_dists.pdf}}
```

If I search with greedy matching, I get the results I expect:

```
[user@host test]$ grep '\\includegraphics.*df' test.txt
\centerline{\includegraphics[width=0.50 \columnwidth]{example_graph.pdf}}
\centerline{\includegraphics[width= 0.8 \columnwidth]{1y26_energy_dists.pdf}}
===========================================================================================================
```

If I use lazy evaluation, however, I get no results:

```
[user@host test]$ grep '\\includegraphics.*?df' test.txt
===========================================================================================================
```

What gives? Why does using lazy evaluation not match what is essentially the same pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.*?` or lazy mode is not supported everywhere. You will have to use `grep -P` or grep in perl mode to achieve it.

Comment: Probably `grep -E` suffices

Comment: @fedorqui grep -E still matches greedily i guess